# count how many duplicate keys are in array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, key

```
[
    {
        "playerId":3207,
        "playerName":"RyanGarbutt",
        "playerPos":"C",
        "playerApiId":"5079"
    },
    {
        "playerId":3238,
        "playerName":"Max Domi",
        "playerPos":"C",
        "playerApiId":"5412"
    },
    {
        "playerId":3240,
        "playerName":"AnthonyDuclair",
        "playerPos":"LW",
        "playerApiId":"5441"
    }
]
```

1-> I want to count playerPos(C,LW) occurrences?
2-> How to get data in format like[{"c":"2"},{"LW":"1"}]

Comment: Post any code you have so far.

Comment: Is there any problem in writing a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$arr = '[{"playerId":3207,"playerName":"RyanGarbutt","playerPos":"C","playerApiId":"5079"},{"playerId":3238,"playerName":"Max Domi","playerPos":"C","playerApiId":"5412"},{"playerId":3240,"playerName":"AnthonyDuclair","playerPos":"LW","playerApiId":"5441"}]';
$arr = json_decode( $arr, true );

$result = array_reduce( $arr , function( $c, $v ) {
    isset( $c[ $v[ "playerPos" ] ] ) ? $c[ $v[ "playerPos" ] ]++ : $c[ $v[ "playerPos" ] ] = 1;
    return $c;
}, array() );


echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [C] => 2
    [LW] => 1
)
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: I'd advise against answering questions where the person asking the question has apparently not expended any effort into finding a solution themselves.  You'll only encourage people to treat Stack Overflow as a source of free labour.

Answer (score 0):

Without loop, conditions and callback function.

```
$arr = '[{"playerId":3207,"playerName":"RyanGarbutt","playerPos":"C","playerApiId":"5079"},{"playerId":3238,"playerName":"Max Domi","playerPos":"C","playerApiId":"5412"},{"playerId":3240,"playerName":"AnthonyDuclair","playerPos":"LW","playerApiId":"5441"}]';
$arr = json_decode( $arr, true );
$result = array_count_values(array_column($arr,"playerPos"));
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
    Array ( 
          [C] => 2 
          [LW] => 1 
)
```

Working example
[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UJaRZ)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this :

1/ First, create two var you will use as counter of occurences of "C" and "LW" :

```
$C  = 0;
$LW = 0;
```

2/ Loop through your array with a foreach loop and test each time if the value of your obj for the key "playerPos" is equal to "C" or "LW", then add +1 for your counter var :

```
foreach($array as $obj) {
    $test = $obj['playerPos'];
    if ($test == "C")
        $C++;
    else if ($test == "LW")
        $LW++;
}
```

3/ Then you need to check the value of each var to know the number of occurences.

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}

$data =
    '[{
    "playerId":3207,"playerName":"RyanGarbutt","playerPos":"C","playerApiId":"5079"},{
    "playerId":3238,"playerName":"Max Domi","playerPos":"C","playerApiId":"5412"},{
    "playerId":3240,"playerName":"AnthonyDuclair","playerPos":"LW","playerApiId":"5441"}]';

$data=json_decode($data,true);

$uniqueArray = unique_multidim_array($data,'playerPos');

print_r($uniqueArray);

print_r(count($uniqueArray));
```